# How do programs link with one another?

Tags: path, linker

I have several questions that are related to how programs link to one another.

Suppose I open a Java applet in Google Chrome. How does Google Chrome know where to find Java on my computer?

Suppose I include a standard library in a C program. How does the compiler know where to find that library?

Suppose I download one program that depends on another program. For example, BCFtools depends on the zlib library. How do I ensure that the first program can find and use the second program?

I have some familiarity with how the PATH variable is used in bash. However, I don't understand how some programs are able to "find" other programs that have been installed. Sorry if this is a rudimentary question but I failed to find anything on this online.